# removing grub from old macbook

Tags: lubuntu, macbook

I got an old macbook from a relative asnd looked at it. It has a no longer supported mac os version and a discontinued windows xp. i installed lubuntu 14.04 to see if it would run faster which it did. I deleted the linux partitions  on the hard drive from a live cd. I used Boot repair to remove grub and fix the boot manager on XP. I reboot the macbook and  hold the alt button to choose which 2 operating to boot into. I can boot into mac OS but, when trying to boot into windows XP I get a grub rescue. I done this before on other pcs but not a macbook. Am I doing something wrong?